# HTML to TCPDF page

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I need help with a small code. I have created a HTML page that has many author names as a link. I have also created a custom pdf generator using tcpdf. Now, I need to know how do I get the authors name mentioned in the HTML on to the pdf PHP page?

HTML page is not a form. So i reckon I cant use $_POST or &_Get?

Comment: you could actually share some code and explain what you did, where you got stuck to get better help

Comment: You have to pass authors name to server using query string or ajax

Comment: You need to give some more details - for example, how are you getting the list of authors' names? You will need to show the code you have tried. Can I also suggest some PHP tutorials, as it seems you're stuck on a fundamental concept of web development.

Comment: Thanks guys for coming back, I have done hard coding. So say I have two names that have links. These links generate a pdf. If i have to mention in the pdf who created the pdf depending on what link the user has clicked. how do i do that?